# Excel VBA - Adding a row with an absolute reference. How do I continue the numerical sequence? 1,2,3 etc.

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro that adds a row and pulls down the formula from the row above. This works well, except with my absolute reference. I need a code that delivers on my desired state below. I'm a newbie at this so if you could add into my code that would be greatly appreciated!!

Current State - VBA Add Row code (below) delivers:

```
$B$1
$B$1
$B$1
```

Desired State - Code delivers:

```
$B$1
$B$2
$B$3
```

Current VBA code is:

```
Sub Insert_Row()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.Goto Reference:="Insert_Row"
Dim insRows As Long
insRows = ActiveCell.Row
Selection.EntireRow.Insert

Range("B" & insRows - 1, "B" & insRows - 1).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range _
("B" & insRows - 1, "B" & insRows), Type:=xlFillValues

ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
End Sub
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you using an absolute reference if you really want a relative reference?

Comment: Because I need to convert to a relative reference to continue the sequence eg. 1,2,3. I then want to make the cells absolute so that when I filter and sort the content I do not get !Value errors. I have just solved this issue by adding in code that makes the whole column absolute after I have increased the sequence e.g., B1,B2,B3,B4 and then the whole column becomes absolute eg. $B$1, $B$2 etc. I'll post the code in the answer section of this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue by making all cells in Column B Absolute once I had completed by VBA code. I did this by:

```
Dim LastCell As Range

Set LastCell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Range("B1", LastCell).Formula = Application.ConvertFormula _
(Formula:=Range("B1", LastCell).Formula, FromReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
ToReferenceStyle:=xlA1, ToAbsolute:=xlAbsolute)
```